# How to make scoreboard points?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am working on a Minecraft map where two teams have to get to the other side first. I want it to be that the first team to 3 points wins. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Answer (score 3):

1. Setup a scoreboard for both teams:

   ```
   /scoreboard objectives add OBJNAME dummy
   /scoreboard objectives add OBJNAME2 dummy
   ```

Change OBJNAME to any name you want it to be. Don't change "dummy".

2. If team A wins, add 1 to the objective 1. Team B, add 1 to objective 2.

   ```
   /scoreboard players add @a OBJNAME 1
   ```

Change the OBJNAME to either team A/B as you made above. Don't change number 1.

To see when a team wins, you need command blocks with `testfor` command:

```
/testfor @p[score_OBJNAME_min=3]
```

Put that again in another command block with its other OBJNAME. Put a comparator on that command block and then another one to do whatever you want when a team gets to 3.